# Ruby on Rails - Savon certificate request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, savon

I'm trying to consume a soap web service using Ruby on Rails and *gem* **[Savon](http://savonrb.com/)**.

I'm doing as follows:

```
Savon.client(
    wsdl: 'web_service_url',
    ssl_verify_mode: :peer, 
    ssl_cert_file: 'cert_path', 
    ssl_cert_key_file: 'key_path'
).operations
```

And then got the Error: `HTTPI::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: certificate verify failed`

But if i make a request with **CURL** using the same **certificate** and **key**, works perfectly.

```
curl -k --cert 'cert_path' --key 'key_path 'web_service_url'
```

What is the problem, how to fix it?

Comment: Sometimes this relates to what crypto library Ruby was compiled against, although occasionally it's a problem with wildly out of date versions of Ruby. What platform and Ruby version are you running?

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

what is the output of

```
print OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
```

What about ignoring the certificate and specify

```
:ssl_verify_mode: :none
```

Comment: If i set **ssl_verify_mode** to **none**, i got: `HTTPI::SSLError: SSL_read: ssl handshake failure`

Comment: OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
`=> "OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015"`

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.1.6p336 on Windows 7x64, my OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION shows "1.0.1l 15 Jan 2015". I wonder why the :none call didn't go through. Have eliminated the other parameters? (ssl_cert_*)

Comment: The problem occurred because the server had not the CA keys from this certificate. After added, it works well.